# How to remove a subView from detailView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I have a table in my masterView and in my detailView i have some imageView, based on different row selection in my masterView i have to remove ImageView and add some other views. Im unable to remove the ImageView.... any help ??? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
for (UIView *view in masterView.subviews){
   if (view == yourImageView) {
       [view removeFromSuperview];            
   }
}
```

Comment: even though i check for view==imageview.view, its not entering the if condition :(

Comment: it was wrong it should not be yourImageView.view. it should be yourImageView

Comment: -(id) initWithString:(int)idValue {
    self = [super init];     
    if(self) {    
        for (UIView *sub in [self.view subviews]) {
            
            if (sub == scrollView) {
                [sub removeFromSuperview];            
            }
        }
}}

Comment: here im trying to remove a scrollView

Comment: where do you add the scrollView to your masterview?

Comment: in my masterView, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

    detailViewObj = [[detailViewController alloc] initWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[IdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]]];


In my detailView

    -(id) initWithString:(int)idValue 
    { 
    self = [super init]; 
    if(self) {
     for (UIView *sub in [self.view subviews]) 
    { 
    if (sub == scrollView) { [sub removeFromSuperview]; 
    }
    }
    }
    }

Comment: it seems like your scrollView is not attached to your DetailViewController.view. Are you using IB or are you doing this programatically?

Comment: can you post your whole DetailViewController.m?

Comment: -(void)method
{
creating scroll view added to self.view
}
this method im calling in viewDidLoad
and based on row selection in masterView, im trying to remove the scrollView......sorry cant post full code its not allowing me...

Answer (score 0):

first you provide tag values other than 0 to all your imageview

and then

```
for (UIView *sub in [self.view subviews]) {
         use tag to find proper view and remove it from superView
    }
```

Comment: if i check for any imageView or any tag....its not entering the if condition... :(

Comment: just put `if(sub.tag == 'YOUR_TAG') [sub removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: if after putting this code if condition is not working then check that you get proper value from your table selection method

Comment: Im passing the correct values from my masterView, i can print the value, but when i check if there exist any imageView in my detailView, its failing....

Comment: does that imageviews have the tag value set and are same values you passed to the function call?